# How to vertically center only one flex item and not another?

Tags: css, flexbox

[the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3u1cq54w/)

I want to always vertically center the bottom flex item but keep the top flex item where it is.

I don't know if there's a way to do this with flexbox but I would prefer to do that over using absolute positioning.

Using `space-between` sticks it to the bottom, and then `space-around` centers both, but I just want to center the bottom one.

Comment: I see you have a fiddle, but you really need to add HTML / CSS /Javascript etc...

Comment: Yeah nevermind that question answers my question. I used the invisible flex item method.